# Bash script wildcard not working with existing file

Tags: bash, hdfs, wildcard

I have a script that assigns a hdfs file path with wildcard to a variable, but the wildcard somehow doesn't work. So I wrote this test script, created a file `some-file.txt` in my home directory

```
FILEPATH=~/some*
echo $(ls $FILEPATH)
echo $FILEPATH

APPJAR=hdfs:///user/myusername/myproject/lib/myproject*.jar
echo $(hdfs dfs -ls $APPJAR)
echo $APPJAR
```

And the output is surprising to me since the first 3 lines produced what I expected but the `hdfs` lines did not.

```
/home/myusername/some-file.txt
/home/myusername/some-file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 3 myusername supergroup 188267249 2018-04-19 23:20 hdfs:///user/myusername/myproject/lib/myproject-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-f7b.jar
hdfs:///user/myusername/myproject/lib/myproject*.jar
```

Obviously, the file exists in HDFS since the `hdfs dfs -ls` command worked. But why does the `APPJAR` variable not become the actual file name? Is the problem in the hdfs command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical thing here is that the shell doesn't recognize hdfs:// URLs; in that case I'm pretty sure the expansion is being done by the `hdfs` command (or *not* done, if there's no `hdfs` command). When the shell sees `hdfs:///user/myusername/myproject/lib/myproject*.jar`, it looks for a directory (under the current working directory) named "hdfs:" (yes, ":" is a legal thing to have in a filename), and a "user" subdirectory under that, etc. Not finding them, it leaves the wildcard unexpanded.

I have several general suggestions:

- Don't use `echo $(somecommand)`, just run the command directly. Capturing the command's output with `$( )` and then turning that back into output with `echo` just adds an extra layer of confusion.
- Use `set -x` to make the shell print commands before executing them, which'll let you see what expansions are happening where. For instance, you'll see that when you assign `FILEPATH=~/some*`, the `~` is expanded to your home directory's path *before* the assignment is done, but the `*` doesn't get expanded until later.
- Put double-quotes around variable references if you don't want them to be split into words and have embedded wildcards expanded. `echo "$variable"` will print the contents of `$variable`, while `echo $variable` will expand wildcards before printing it.
- Don't use all-caps variable names; use lowercase or mixed-case instead. There are a large number of all-caps variables with special meanings, and if you ever try to use one of those for something else (`PATH`, for example) you're going to have problems.

Comment: Great points for a newbie bash scripter like me. Appreciate the input. Accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that Bash is not automagically aware of arbitrary protocols like HDFS. You wouldn't expect `https://example.org/*.txt` to expand, for example. If you install an HDFS filesystem driver and mount the directory it will complete just fine.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense... So basically, the thing I want to achieve must be done by parsing the output of `hdfs dfs -ls`, correct?